# Powershell Active Directory Query

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

New to using Powershell, so I apologize for any noobness that I show.

I'm trying to extract user names, active status, Expiration Dates and Titles from Active Directory.

My Powershell command is:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=XXX,DC=XXXX" |
    Select-Object Name, GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, enabled, Title, AccountExpirationDate |
    Export-Csv -Path c:\users\myname\ADUsersWithExpirationDate.csv
```

The query runs successfully, but does not ever show a Title or Expiration Date even though some user accounts have either or both values in AD.  Also status (Enabled) does not always populate: the returned values are True, False, or null.  All of the Nulls (that I've checked) are active user accounts, but appear to be in non-standard OU's (Admins for example).

Any insight or recommendations are very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the AD cmdlets don't return all the attributes. You need to use the `-Properties` parameter to add the AccountExpirationDate and Title attributes to the query.  Your command should look something like:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=XXX,DC=XXXX" -Properties 'Title','AccountExpirationDate' | 
Select-Object Name, GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, enabled, Title, AccountExpirationDate | 
Export-Csv -Path c:\users\myname\ADUsersWithExpirationDate.csv
```